# How to update a field using another field value in MongoDB/Mongoose and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection named Price in MongoDB database, with the fields price, shopLng,shopLat and geoDist. I want, for all the documents of this collection, to update the geoDist field, depending on the shopLat and shopLng fields. The variables geoLat and geoLng are known. I tried that:

```
await Price.find().snapshot().forEach(function(doc) {
      latmy = doc.shopLat; //tou ekastote shop
      lngmy = doc.shopLng;
      doc.geoDist = latmy + lngmy +geoLat + geoLng;
      doc.save(); 
  });
```

But if run the code showed above, that is supposed to do the job for all the documents, there must be a problem, because I get this error:
TypeError: Price.find(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: `find()` is asynchronous, that's why you get the error.  Move the `forEach` in the callback or use `.then()`

Comment: how should I use then?

Comment: `Model.find().then((result) => { result.forEach(...) })`